# Explanation on expectation of Cauchy mean

Tags: statistics, expected-value

It might seem trivial but I couldn't understand where the number 2 (highlighted) came from in the last equality of the following text. Could you please explain? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with symmetry? Look at the limits of the integration ...

Comment: Yes, I realised that the limit changed from (-$\infty$, $\infty$) to (0, $\infty$) because |$x$| is always positive. But what's the need for 2? I meant |-5| = 5, not **2** * 5?

Comment: $$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \int_{-\infty}^0 + \int_0^{\infty} = \ldots
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{|x|}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx 
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{|x|}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx + \int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{|x|}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx - \int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{x}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \\
\end{align}
Taking $t = -x$ in the $2^{nd}$ integral, it evaluates to -
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{x}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx
&= \int_{\infty}^{0}\frac{-t}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+(-t)^2}d(-t) \\
&= - \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt \\
\end{align}
Thus, 
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{|x|}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx 
&= 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, @Ishan Deo. Much appreciated.